# How to specify this specific xpath

Tags: xml, xpath

I wanted to replace the content under `.oe_structure` class but I'm confused of the divs bec some have the same class name. I tried getting the xpath from Chrome Devtools but I always got errors.

```
<template id="contactus" name="Contact us" page="True">
    <t t-call="website.layout">
      <div id="wrap">
        <div class="oe_structure"/>
            <div class="container">
                <h1>Contact us</h1>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-8">
                        <div class="oe_structure"> <!-- How to get this path? --> 
                            <div>
                                <p>Contact us about anything related to our company or services.</p>
                                <p>We'll do our best to get back to you as soon as possible.</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="text-center mt64" name="mail_button">
                            <a t-attf-href="mailto:{{ res_company.email }}" class="btn btn-primary" id="o_contact_mail">Send us an email</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4 mb32">
                        <t t-call="website.company_description"/>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        <div class="oe_structure"/>
      </div>
    </t>
</template>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I already get the correct path which is `//div[@class='row']/div[1]/div[1]`

Answer (score 0):

You can use this xpath also

```
//div[@class='row']//div[@class='oe_structure']
```